# How to run two function on useEffect at once on first render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getCategory = () => {
    allcategory().then((res) => {
      if (res.data.error) {
        console.log("error");
        setValues({ ...values,
          message: res.data.error
        });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values,
          categories: res.data.category,
          formData: new FormData(),
        })
      }
    })
  }

  const getPublisher = () => {
    allpublisher().then((res) => {
      if (res.data.error) {
        console.log("error");
        setValues({ ...values,
          message: res.data.error
        });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values,
          publishers: res.data.publisher,
          formData: new FormData(),
        });
      }
    })
  }
  getCategory()
  getPublisher()
}, [])
```

When I try to add two function on `useEffect` it doesn't render any data but show data on first render if only one function is present on `useEffect`

Comment: I want to know the purpose of this. Do you want to merge 2 apis response and show together? or want to show one response that respond first come?

Comment: Are the API calls getting fired ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Multiple API endpoint in useEffect React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840557/call-multiple-api-endpoint-in-useeffect-react)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using promises, you can implement promise chaining here like

```
getCategory().then(()=>getPublisher())
```

But instead of having multiple promise chains, you can implement async await functions

```
const getData = async() => {
 await getCategory()
 await getPublisher()
}

useEffect(() => {
getData()
},[])
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you miss async function.
I think this should like this

`const getCategory = async () =>`

`const getPublisher = async () =>`

And with my opinion, you should refractor like this:

```
const getCategory = async () => {
 // ...do sth
}

const getPublisher = async () => {
 // ...do sth
}

useEffect(() => {
 getCategory();
 getPublisher();
},[])
```

Comment: Why aren't you awaiting the function calls inside `useEffect()`, this doesn't make any sense and leads to unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Wrap your outside functions in useCallback and use those methods in the useEffect with their functions names in the array dependency !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).